# kubernetes - dynamically change namespace of RC

Tags: namespaces, kubernetes

Do you know if there is a way to dynamically change the namespace of a running RC or pod in kubernetes?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: What's the request? Let me guess,  suppose you have `default` and `kube-system` namespaces, the pod running in default and you want to change it to kube-system? Right?

Comment: Exactly, you also could have said `namespace1` and `namespace2`. Thanks for your help.

Comment: no, I don't think kubernetes support this feature currently.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can not change the namespace of a running resource:

**A resource with the same name might already exist in another namespace, making a rename difficult and unpredictable**

Comment: Theoretically yes (assuming you do not create naming collisions):
The kubernetes "environment" persists its configuration in etcd following the given ruleset for the resource. The executing components (kubelet in this scenario) read from the API server which gets its state from etcd. So if you change something in etcd, it should be reflected back. I can not predict the networking side of a change like this, and other possible side effects, which can be really cluster setup dependent.
I know this hack at least works for the DNS (used it when I broke a cluster)